# Calendar function won't trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css, triggers, calendar

I am trying to trigger a calendar popup on an image with JavaScript, but for some reason, it isn't working correctly.  Any advice?

Here is my code:

```
<input size="12" id="f_date1" class="fields"/>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="f_btn1" title="Select your date and time."><img src="Icons/calendar.png" alt="Calendar" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a></td>

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date1",
        trigger    : "f_btn1",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 12,
        dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"
      });
    //]]></script>
```

The CSS and the JS are included in the header.

---

**UPDATE**

I did that with

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date10",
        trigger    : "f_btn10",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 12,
        dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"
      });

      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date11",
        trigger    : "f_btn11",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 12,
        dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"
      });

      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date12",
        trigger    : "f_btn12",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 12,
        dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"
      });

      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date13",
        trigger    : "f_btn13",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 12,
        dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"
      });

      Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "f_date14",
        trigger    : "f_btn14",
        onSelect   : function() { this.hide() },
        showTime   : 12,
        dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"
      });

<script>
```

but no dice. It still refuses to fire even with the CSS and JS added...

Comment: Where do you connect the code and the HTML together? So something like `document.getElementById('t_date1').addEventListener(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is [jsCalendar plugin](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/doc/).
Your trigger: "*f_btn1*" should be an **id** attribute, not **class** in the anchor HTML tag.
Like this:

```
<a href="#" id="f_btn1" title="Select your date and time.">
```

Instead of this:

```
<a href="#" class="f_btn1" title="Select your date and time.">
```

Also, you don't need to wrap *img* within *anchor* tag. In the calendar documentation you read about "trigger" parameter:

```
trigger — an ID of a <button> element (in fact any element type) that should trigger the popup calendar (the calendar hooks on the “onclick” event).
```

Comment: I got the calendar to fire with <a href="#" id="f_btn1" onClick=Calendar.setup();"><img src="Icons/calendar.png" alt="Calendar" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>; however, there are four instances of the same code, and the calendar only fires on the first one!  This is driving me crazy!  Why does the identical code on the same page and a few others, sometimes work, and sometimes doesnt!?

Comment: _four instances of the same code_ you mean there are four same elements with the same __id__ attribute? There can only be __one__ id of the specified value - this is the HTML DOM rule and you can't cheat on it (anyway you shouldn't - probably the Calendar prevents it). If you want to implement calendar trigger on 4 different "buttons" I suggest putting 4 buttons with different IDs and implementing four separate Calendar.setup methods.